# How to completely hide an Element from webpage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there any way to completely hide an element on a webpage?? Like with  **display:none** or **visibility:hidden**, though it seems elements are no longer visible but can be seen by un-checking css options from developer tools the likes of which can be found with Microsoft Edge that provides the privilege to do that.

Comment: The only way to prevent that is to completely remove the element from the DOM

Comment: If you don't want your element to be in the code, don't put it in the code.

Comment: add javascript code to remove it on page load. But will still be visible in source code thought

Comment: Can you provide the use-case for this?  What use would you have for an element that you can't see *or access* in any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store HTML in `variable` or `LocalStorage` and remove completely.
If you want to show again, you need to know where to restore it. you can keep it in another variant.

```
var html = $('#hidden-element').html();
$('#hidden-element').remove();
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this in css.

display:none !important;

Comment: You can still deselect/un-check this style using the developer tools.